# Using onclick event with a function with more than one argument in Template literals

Tags: javascript, node.js, templates, onclick, template-literals

What is the correct way to write a function with more than one argument when using javascript post es6 template literals called by an onclick event?

my code :

```
function displayImg(imageUrl, gameName, gameSummary, gameYear, cardId) {
    cardId = cardId.toString();
    resultImg.innerHTML += `
        <a class='text-dark ml-2' ><button onclick="${feedDb(imageUrl,gameName,gameSummary,gameYear)}" id='front' type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary'>Save</button></a>
        <a class='text-dark ml-2' ><button onclick="flipCard(${cardId})" id='front' type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary'> + d'info</button></a>`
}
```

This way, the code is working but the function 'feedDb' is launched automatically (without clicking on the button). (i don't want this behaviour)

if i call the function feedDb like the following, it dosen't work and the entire app crash (nodeJs).:

```
<button onclick="feedDb(${imageUrl},${gameName},${gameSummary},${gameYear})">
```

I tried the following but with no more success:

```
<button onclick="feedDb(${imageUrl,gameName,gameSummary,gameYear})">
```

Only the gameyear is defined in this case... and  it return an error of course.

What is the correct syntaxe when using a function with more than one argument inside a string based on template literals in JavaScript post ES6 please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are programmatically generating JavaScript embedded inside HTML.

Think about what the result is going to look like. Better yet, **look** at it. Don't just assign to `resultImg.innerHTML`. Store it in a variable and `console.log` it.

The output is going to look something like this:

```
<button onclick="feedDb(http://example.com/,football,
```

You're outputting the values of the variables into the JavaScript where a URL will be treated as a syntax error, and a word will be treated as a variable name.

String literals need to be surrounded by quotes!

---

You have a second problem. `<a>` elements **may not** contain `<button>` elements (or vice versa). You aren't linking anywhere, don't use an `<a>`.

And a third: An `id` must be **unique** within the document.

---

That said, the data might include characters with special meaning (like `"`, `'` or `&`) which would break the generated result.

It's generally pretty dangerous (and hard to debug) to generate source code by mashing strings together.

Consider using DOM manipulation instead. It is more verbose but considerably safer.

```
function displayImg(imageUrl, gameName, gameSummary, gameYear, cardId) {
        cardId = cardId.toString();

        const b1 = document.createElement("button");
        b1.classList.add("btn", "btn-sm",  "btn-outline-secondary");
        b1.type = "button";
        b1.id = "front";
        b1.textContent = "Save";
        b1.addEventListener("click", () => feedDb(imageUrl,gameName,gameSummary,gameYear));
        resultImg.appendChild(b1);

        const b2 = document.createElement("button");
        b2.classList.add("btn", "btn-sm",  "btn-outline-secondary");
        b2.type = "button";
        b2.id = "not-front"; 
        b2.textContent = "+ d'info";
        b2.addEventListener("click", () => flipCard(cardId));
        resultImg.appendChild(b2);
}
```

Comment: Hello Quentin, thank you for the reply, i have done a mistake when i create this topic, when i create the topic i would like to show the different tries i have done  and this is why i have 2 equal id(s) (i copied quickly the line just bellow the the one where i call the feedDb() function. my bad. And thank you for pointing me for the <a> tag when using a <button> tag also. i copied this peace of code somewhere and adapt it for my need so, other peoples seems to use this weird syntax too maybe.

Comment: I logged the complete string conatained in my resultImg.innerHTML and  look what it look like : <button onclick="undefined" id="add" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Save</button>
                <button onclick="flipCard(1)" id="front" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary"> + d'info</button>, (sorry, i don't know how to post the following code in code tag when answere someone , there is no options like when i create a topic) . anyway the code is executed like i said before! i don't understand what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

It's already done.

but i resend you here what is the correct syntax :

```
resultImg.innerHTML = `
....
<button onclick="feedDb('${imageUrl}','${gameName}','${gameYear}')" id='add' type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary'>Save</button></a>
....`
```

we must surround the variables like in my example, this is the right syntax!

i hope, it help!

Answer (score 0):

first of all thank you!

because of you @Quentin, i improved not also my code and my knowledge but i will take more consideration of the use of the console.log when i generate JavaScript embedded inside HTML.

my first  attempt was to log my working code and i saw that strange behaviour (and that the feedDb return some undefined code (even if the code was executed automatically)!!

result of the console.log(result.Img.innerHTML)  :

```
<button onclick="**undefined**" id="add" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Save</button> <button onclick="flipCard(1)" id="front" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary"> + d'info</button>
```

secondly, i give a try and i surrounded my variables by quotes like the following:

```
        <button onclick="feedDb('${imageUrl}','${gameName}', '${gameSummary}', '${gameYear}')" id='add' type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary'>Save</button></a>
```

and because i use the console.log(result.Img.innerHTML), i was able to see, what i haven't seen before from many of my tests: 
one of my variable contain a full text with coma separated sentences , and when passed into the function feedDb(), each new comas from this sentences where interpreted like i send a new variable in my argument list. this trown errors.

At the moment, i have retired the variable containing the full text, i must search how i can escape these comas separated sentences to be able to pass it to my function now.

my code is well executed only when i click on my button and i can see exactly what is going on and what i am sending to the feedDb() function! thanks

```
        <button onclick="feedDb('${imageUrl}','${gameName}','${gameYear}')" id='add' type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary'>Save</button></a>
```