# How to pass Object as parameter to a function onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I am facing some issues while trying to pass JSON object as a parameter to function!
but on that function, while consoling log the data I am getting [object:object].

Here is my code:

```
function buildTable(data) {
  var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  table.innerHTML = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var row = `<tr class="item-id-${data[i].id}"> <td>${data[i].name}</td> <td>${data[i].audio_muted}</td> <td>${data[i].video_muted}</td> <td><button id="audio_handle" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="handleMembers('${data[i]}')">Video</button></td>`;

    table.innerHTML += row;
  }
}

function handleMembers(data) {
  console.log("data = >", data); //= [object:object]
}
```

The issue is when I am calling handle function from the button inside template literal string I m getting [object:object] as output

Where I am going wrong?

Comment: Hi @CS. what is your ultimate goal? You need to print the entire object or only one or more properties of the object?

Comment: Your JS is vulnerable to XSS attacks btw.

Comment: "while consoling log the data I am getting [object:object]" - that's normal because `data` isn't a `string` or `number` value, so what's the problem?

Comment: @Dai Sir I don't know how to use that thing I tried JSON.parse but it didn't worked

Comment: use `console.log( "data: %o", data );` - notice the use of `%o`.

Comment: @CS. Also, **never** call me "sir". _Yegods_. I'm not knighted.

Comment: @MatteoPHRE I need entire object of a particular row.

Comment: `\`...onclick="handleMembers('${JSON.stringify(data)}')"....\`` ?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I am getting  Invalid or unexpected token err

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61069991/using-onclick-event-with-a-function-with-more-than-one-argument-in-template-lite — Don't use template strings for this. Use DOM.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp — **No, that won't work**.  JSON.stringify will put `"` characters around the strings in the data and the attribute value is delimited with `"` characters.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed a few points in the following snippet and added some HTML and some sample data:

```js
// some sample data for illustration:
const data=[{id:1,name:"Harry",audio_muted:1,video_muted:1},{id:2,name:"Ron",audio_muted:1,video_muted:0},{id:3,name:"Hermiony",audio_muted:0,video_muted:1},{id:4,name:"Ginny",audio_muted:0,video_muted:1}];

const tbl=document.getElementById("myTable");
tbl.innerHTML = data.map((itm,i)=>`<tr class="item-id-${itm.id}"> <td>${itm.name}</td> <td>${itm.audio_muted}</td> <td>${itm.video_muted}</td> <td><button data-id="${i}" class="btn btn-primary">Video</button></td>`).join("\n")

tbl.addEventListener("click",ev=>{
  if (ev.target.tagName==="BUTTON")
    console.log("data = >", data[ev.target.dataset.id]) ; //= [object:object]
})
```

```html
<table id="myTable"></table>
```

As @Quentin already mentioned you should not include JavaScript code within a template string. This gets too complicated to read and to maintain. Instead I used a delegated event-handler on the table itself to listen for the click on the `button` elements. By doing all this there was no need anymore for the two named functions.

Another thing that comes to my mind is: Never use `element.innerHTML += ...` inside a for loop as this will potentially become really slow. It is generally better to assemble the whole HTML string *in one go* and then assign it to the `innerHTML` property.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the wrong approach to do that. You should try to create the element using the DOM api and add the eventListener to the selected element, something like:

```
function buildTable(data) {
 const table = document.getElementById("myTable");

 for(let d of data) {
    const tr = document.createElement("tr");      
    const td1 = document.createElement("td");
    td1.textContent = d.name;       
    
    const td2 = document.createElement("td");
    td2.textContext = d.audio_muted;
    
    const td3 = document.createElement("td");
    td3.textContent = d.video_muted;
    
    const tdButton = document.createElement("button");
    tdButton.classList.add("btn", "btn-primary");
    tdButton.addEventListener("click", () => handleMembers(d));
    
    tr.appendChild(td1)
    tr.appendChild(td2)
    tr.appendChild(td3)
    tr.appendChild(tdButton);
    
    table.appendChild(tr)

 }
}
```